# React Native upload image

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

Mobile application for upload image from Gallery / Camera , we need to ask run time permission.
If permission granted, we need to use.

const data = new FormData();
data.append("file", {
uri: file_parse_uri,
type: "image/jpeg",
name: file_parse_name,
});

headers: {
Authorization: 'if need',
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
},

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think that you're performing the request wrong, try this instead :

Note : change the pickImage function so that the setUri takes (result.assets[0]) instead of (result.assets[0].uri)

```
const formBody = new FormData();
    formBody.append('image', {
        uri: uri.uri,
        name: uri.name,
        type: uri.type,
    });
```

then instead of passing {  image : uri } next to url  try to passe this : { body: formBody }